# Is there such a thing as a Boron-Carbon-Lithium alloy?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I am trying to create an alloy with heat resistance for a project. Is there such a thing as a boron-lithium-carbon alloy, and are there any benefits to it?

Answer (score 2):

In the study [Compound Formation in the Systems Lithium-Carbon and Lithium-Boron](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1151-2916.1967.tb14985.x/full), Journal of the American Ceramic Society, Volume 50, Issue 10, October 1967, Pages 520–523

molten lithium metal was added to $\ce{B_{4.0}C}$ in proportions ranging from 7 to 71% lithium.

> a  substitution  reaction  evidently  occurs  between 
>   lithium  and  boron  carbide  which  leads  to  the  formation  of 
>   lithium  boride  and  lithium  carbide

Answer (score 1):

Chemistry does not work quite like that. Going around the periodic table and poking elements at random (or just for the sake of their atomic number, disregarding other properties) is hardly leading to any good.

As for the $\ce{Li-B-C}$ ternary system, I strongly suspect that it has not been studied in full. (Good to know it has been studied at least partially, but there might be many more unknowns to it.) Also, I suspect that there are some compounds containing all three elements (you may call them *alloys* if you like, though most chemists wouldn't), but those would be unsuitable for your project because of other requirements which you didn't specify. Do you want your alloy to be stable in the air, for starters?

Comment: Ok. I should have gotten a little more information beforehand. I was looking for an inert element, that was very light, preferably with some heat resistance. I was using Lewis dot structures to try to form the compound. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. Well, these things are going to be light for sure, but hardly inert.